# Webpack environment variable NODE_ENV vs cli params --env

Tags: javascript, webpack

what's the difference between set environment variable and cli environment options?

for example

```
cross-env NODE_ENV=production webpack
```

then

```
const isProd = process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production'
```

or

```
webpack --env.production
```

then

```
module.exports = function (env) {
 ....
}
```

which is better?

Answer (score 0):

webpack --env.production is prob better since it will ensure that all variables that should be set are set. Admittedly, it is probably only setting NODE_ENV=production - however, in the future things might change and this approach will ensure you are always taking the best current approach.